# node.js mysql2 how to save from select in var

Tags: node.js, node-mysql2

have mysql database with some fields

```
con.query(
           'SELECT rk_individual_id FROM  `valid_users` WHERE `login` = ? ',
           ["ya010156gmv"],
           function(err,result){

            if (err) {
                console.log('db fetch error',error);
                throw err;
            }

            else{
                console.log(result)
               var rk_individual_id = result.rk_individual_id
               console.log(rk_individual_id)
            }
```

console.log(result)

```
[
  TextRow { rk_individual_id: '9061085e-b0fb-11e4-b5d2-2c768a534abf' }
]
```

result save undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value in result[0].rk_individual_id